# How can I see what physical hunks are not in one branch from another?

Tags: git

There is a branch `topic1` that was originally branched from `master`. Let's say that the original owner of `topic1` didn't do a proper merge of that branch back into `master`, and instead did a cherry pick operation but missed a few commits.

Months pass, and finally I realize `topic1` is still there. At this point, it's been so long that I have no reliable way to determine if the cumulative patch that `topic1` represents is present on `master`.

What I *want* is to be able to do `git diff topic1..master` but *hide* any hunks on `master` that do not exist in `topic1`. Basically I just want to see portion of the diff showing changes in `topic1` that are not present in `master`. Is this possible? And if so, how can I do it?

I'm using Git 2.8+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by using the `--cherry-pick` option of `git log` to get the list of commits from `topic1` the were *not cherry-picked* into `master`.

From the documenation of [`git-log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> **--cherry-pick**
>   Omit any commit that introduces the same change as another commit on the “other side” when the set of commits are limited
>   with symmetric difference.

What's interesting here is that the `--cherry-pick` option uses the commit's *diff* – not the commit's SHA-1 hash – in order to determine whether a commit that introduces the same set of changes is present in another branch.

From the documentation of [`git-cherry`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry), which is related:

> The equivalence test is based on the diff, after removing whitespace
>   and line numbers. git-cherry therefore detects when commits have been
>   "copied" by means of `git-cherry-pick`, `git-am` or `git-rebase`.

Such commits are said to be *patch equivalent*.

So, `git log --cherry-pick master...topic1` will *exclude* the commits from `topic1` that *have* been cherry-picked in `master`, leaving only the ones that are not. We add the `--right-only` option to indicate that we are only interested in seeing commits from the right side of the range, i.e. `topic1`:

```
git log --cherry-pick --right-only master...topic1
```

We might also want to exclude *merge commits* from the selection, so we add the `--no-merges` option:

```
git log --no-merges --cherry-pick --right-only master...topic1
```

Lastly, we add the `--patch` option to get the diff for those commits. The final command then becomes:

```
git log --patch --no-merges --cherry-pick --right-only master...topic1
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, however I would still like to see a diff solution for this. It will handle scenarios where: A cherry picked commit was modified on the destination, or changes were hand-edited (i.e. someone double-fixed a bug without realizing it was already done in another branch), or commits were improperly structured and commits are only partially-present on `master`.

Comment: In that case, I think `git diff master..topic1` should give you the answer you're looking for – it will show you the changes that exist in `topic1` but not in `master`.

Comment: not quite because that will also show all changes on `master` that are not present in `topic1`, even if `topic1` never made any changes to that piece of code. I want to see the diff from the right side only, based on changeset instead of commit. The closest thing I can think of that will get me what I want is: `$ git merge topic1 --no-commit`, then do `git diff`. This will at least show me the changes not present on master, but I have to do a merge to do it.

Comment: Right. Unfortunately, `git diff` doesn't take the same range selection options as `git log` does, so a solution that only relies on `git diff` is out AFAIK.

Comment: @void.pointer: your other alternative is indeed to do a merge now.  Besides using `--no-commit`, another method is to do it on a branch that grows from the current tip of `master`.  This can be a regular branch you create now, or the anonymous branch you get with `git checkout --detach master`.

Comment: @torek detached checkout seems nice, but really only saves me from doing `git reset --hard` when I'm done.

Comment: @void.pointer: precisely. For scripting purposes, this lets you check the merge result automatically and skip some cleanup code for the "nice" cases. Nothing earth-shattering, just convenient.